# duplicate error in import large entery laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

We have code in laravel that get txt file and import each line of txt file in database (about 300,000 Lines)
Everything works fine but when imports about 100,000 line i get duplicate entry error! (but my codes don't have duplicate)
what's the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: with so little information we cannot possibly expect to understand your problem. It's like asking a mechanic to fix your car without looking at the engine.